# AWS: getting limited IAM credentials for DynamoDB without JS SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito

What I want to achieve:
[image: aws cognito dynamodb limited iam http call from browser to the database]

My case described in [this article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/building-fine-grained-authorization-using-amazon-cognito-user-pools-groups/) but I do not want to use SDK on my webpage - I want to keep my app simple and fast, but as it turned out - it is hard to find an example that does not use SDK. I stumped with http call from which I need to get limited IAM credentials for DynamoDB. In my investigation of the documentation, I found method [GetCredentialsForIdentity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognitoidentity/latest/APIReference/API_GetCredentialsForIdentity.html), description:

> Returns credentials for the provided identity ID. Any provided logins
>   will be validated against supported login providers. If the token is
>   for cognito-identity.amazonaws.com, it will be passed through to AWS
>   Security Token Service with the appropriate role for the token.

But on this page not mentioned url for that endpoint. I tried
`https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`
`https://cognito-identity.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`
`https://<mydomain>.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com`

I getting 400 error now, maybe because of incorrect endpoint url. My current code:

```
fetch('https://cognito-identity.us-east-1.amazonaws.com', {
  'method': 'POST',
  'headers': {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.1',
    'X-Amz-Target': 'AWSCognitoIdentityService.GetCredentialsForIdentity',
   },
   'body': '{"IdentityId": "us-east-1:<GUID of the user>"}'
});
```

1) What is the http endpoint?
2) Am I digging in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct endpoint is
`https://cognito-identity.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`
[according to this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html).

Also, I found that I need to provide not a `sub` from `id_token` but firstly [GetId](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognitoidentity/latest/APIReference/API_GetId.html) of the user.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying the same for flutter at the moment - could you please put the details of what and how you achieved this in the answer here please?